Error on GET with authorization-header - only in Browser (CF-RestApi & Angular)
first things first:
we develop our own RestAPI in ColdFusion with follwing headers:
cfheader (name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value="*");
cfheader (name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value="*");
cfheader (name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value="GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS");
cfheader (name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value="true");

The webserver allows all headers and methods - i've asked our sysadmins.
we are coding an angular(18) app (not soo much experience with angular).
We use an interceptor to add the headers.
Our Login is working (post, no auth-header..) in postman & browsers!
After successfull login are two get-calls and here is my understanding-problem:
a)
Without the authorization-header the request is returning 200 ok and the response is as we want (we exclude the needed authorization-part in the api and return the content).
Working Postman AND browsers!
b)
With the authorization-header and a valid token and working authorization-logic is only postman getting a valid response, the browsers are showing an 500er CORS error in the OPTIONS and the GET request.
My question:
why?
i have compared the headers from working-get and the not-working-get-calls - nearly the same.
can someone explain what causes this behaviour?
do the browsers follwing the cors-rules more strictly ? But why does it work without an added header (it doesnt matter how i name it!)?
this is our intercepter:
 if (req.headers.has('no-auth')) {
    req = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.delete('no-auth', 'true'),
      setHeaders: { Accept: 'application/json' },
    });
    return next(req);
  } else {
    /* Token: */
    let Token = localStorage.getItem('Token')
      ? localStorage.getItem('Token')
      : '';
    const auth_headers = req.headers.set('Authorization', `${Token}`);

    // Clone the request and add the authorization header
    const authReq = req.clone({/*auth_headers*/});
    return next(authReq);
  }

...yes the interceptor not finished...
thanks in advance for any help!! :-)
Uwe
EDIT:

angular is running on localhost
I think the problem is somewhere in the OPTIONS-preflight... so this are die API-Headers at the moment:

// Handle CORS preflight request
if (cgi.request_method == "OPTIONS") {
    cfheader(name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value="http://localhost:4004");
    cfheader(name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value="Content-Type, Authorization");
    cfheader(name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    cfheader(name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value="true");
    cfheader(statuscode="200", statustext="OK");
    cfexit();
}

// Your actual API logic here
cfheader(name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value="*");
cfheader(name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value="*");
cfheader(name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
cfheader(name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value="true");


wildcard origins are not allowed when request is credentialed.  " When responding to a credentialed requests request, the server must specify an origin in the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, instead of specifying the "*" wildcard.": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Thanks for your hint! So i have to edit the api. do you know if i have to change the request event in the api, or the the function which i call? i think, i have to change the request event: Check if its get-method and if the needed auth-header is present -> if yes change the Access-Control-Allow-Origin-header to htto://localhost:4004

best not to set any CORS headers and while debugging either use a proxy that makes all requests same localhost: port, or use a browser profile with CORS rules turned off.  That way you can be as secure as possible by making all requests same domain.  (and not risk forgetting to remove those headers when published)

thank you for your tipps! :)
I was able to fix this in the api!
In short:
i made an fuction for the options-method and a function to set the cors-headers:
function setCORSHeaders() {
    pc = getPageContext().getResponse();

    // Allow specific origins (change '*' to your specific domain in production)
    pc.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4004");

    // Allow only specific methods
    pc.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS");

    // Allow only specific headers
    pc.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type, X-API-KEY");

    // Allow credentials if needed
    pc.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
}

the following function is called after the login and needs the authorization header:
remote struct function getData() httpMethod="GET" restpath="Data" produces="application/json"  {
    // Set the CORS headers
    setCORSHeaders();
    var response = {};/* function logic to load the data in the response */ return response; }

to respond a valid options-request i´ve added this function:
which is called on options-request:
remote void function DataOptions() httpMethod="OPTIONS" restpath="Data" output=false produces="application/json"{
    setCORSHeaders();
    RESTResponse = {
        status = 204
    };
    restSetResponse(RESTResponse);
}

this seems to work right now - and yes, i bet here are some improvements to be done ...
